# Response is null in PHP while .Net is giving all text

Tags: c#, php, curl

I'm using cURL in PHP to get id in response but I'm getting empty response. Here is my code:

```
$jsonContent = "{\"param1\" : [{\"subparam1\" : subnumval1,\"subparam2\" : subnumval2 },{\"subparam1\" : subnumval1,\"subparam2\" : subnumval2 }],\"param2\" : \"val2\",\"param3\" : \"val3\"}";

    $url = HTTPS_URL;    
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonContent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonContent))
);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
if($output === false)
{
       echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}else
    {
       echo $output;
    }
```

While I'm trying to get response using .NET (C#),I'm getting the response, here is .NET code:

```
public partial class PostData : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            PostBlockFaceData();

    }

    // POST a JSON string
    void PostBlockFaceData()
    {
        //Create the credentials cache as you can more than one
        CredentialCache tempCache= new CredentialCache();

        //Create the Network username and password
        NetworkCredential secureCred = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

        //Add the login credentials to the credential cache
        parkmeCache.Add(new Uri("HTTPS_URL:443/"), "Basic", secureCred);

        //JSON array in string format
        string jsonContent = "{\"param1\" : [{\"subparam1\" : "subval1",\"subparam2\" : "subval2" },{\"subparam1\" : "subval2",\"subparam2\" : "subparam2" }],\"param2\" : \"val2\",\"param3\" : \"val3\"}";
        //
        string url = HTTPS_URL

        //Create the Webrequest with the URL
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.PreAuthenticate = true; //use authentication
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true; //Use the default credential available
        request.Credentials = parkmeCache; //pass the credential cache to the request object

        //The following is to used to ignore bit matching
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
                    Object sender1,
                    X509Certificate certificate,
                    X509Chain chain,
                    System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };


        request.Method = "POST"; //HTTP VERB
        request.ContentLength = jsonContent.Length; //JSON DATA string length
        request.ContentType = @"application/json"; //The Content type is of application in json format
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); //specified UTF8 standard text coding
        Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent); //converted the json data to bytes because datastream understands that way

        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()) //get the request stream handle
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);  //write the json data to the request stream
        }
        long length = 0;
        string strStatusCode="";
        string strDesc = "";
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) //execute the request and get the response from the call
            {

                length = response.ContentLength; //length of the content
                strStatusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString(); //return the status code OK on success or status error codes like 400, 403 etc.,
                strDesc = response.StatusDescription; //The description has the return value in this case on success returns the Block Face ID
                Response.Write("Status Code : " + strStatusCode + "    ,    Status Description : " + strDesc);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            // Log exception and throw as for GET example above
        }
    }


}
```

Above code is working like charm..I don't know where's the issue in PHP. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That PHP script shouldn't even run due to syntax errors...!?

Comment: @deceze What syntax error you noticed? Because Its running fine and even inserting the record but not giving any response text that's the issue. Please tell me what's the issue

Comment: What does `curl_error()` give you? Assuming that `curl_exec()` returned false.

Comment: Hi Jack, It doesn't giving any error. I've edited PHP code as above.

Comment: Then you have a bad server ;-) btw, you don't need `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` for sure and the `Content-Length` header is created automatically as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would like to thank you all guys who respond me and tried to figure out my issue. After digging much and checking the code I noticed what is the issue.

All I need to do is passing the header like below code

**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);**

Here I'm putting the correct code below.

```
$jsonContent = "{\"param1\" : [{\"subparam1\" : subnumval1,\"subparam2\" : subnumval2 },{\"subparam1\" : subnumval1,\"subparam2\" : subnumval2 }],\"param2\" : \"val2\",\"param3\" : \"val3\"}";

    $url = HTTPS_URL;    
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonContent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonContent))
);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
if($output === false)
{
       echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}else
    {
       echo $output;
    }
```

I hope it'll help other guys who faces / will face the same issue.

Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

> $jsonContent = "{\"param1\" : [{\"subparam1\" : "subval1",\"subparam2\" : "subval2" },{\"subparam1\" : "subval2",\"subparam2\" : "subparam2" }],\"param2\" : \"val2\",\"param3\" : \"val3\"}";

to

> $jsonContent = "{\"param1\" : [{\"subparam1\" : \"subval1\",\"subparam2\" : \"subval2\" },{\"subparam1\" : \"subval2\",\"subparam2\" : \"subparam2\" }],\"param2\" : \"val2\",\"param3\" : \"val3\"}";

You have not escaped all double quotes.

Comment: Hi Bhavik, Thanks for your reply. Actually that value is numeric,I've removed the double quotes. please check now

Comment: can you give me the value you are using for HTTPS_URL?

Comment: URL: https://subdom.domain.com/cgi-bin/db.test?COMMAND=add&TABLE=table_name&USER=1&SUBSYSTEM=JSON