# Explode is not separating a string correctly

Tags: php, explode

I'm getting below string by using cURL. The code can be found in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952156/response-is-null-in-php-while-net-is-giving-all-text#comment20988272_14952156).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK ID=347 Date: Tue, 19 Feb 2013 09:15:25 GMT Server:
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Content-length: 0 Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Now I want ID from the string and for that I've used explode to make an array from the space like below:

```
$getIdElem = explode(' ',$output);
echo '<pre>';print_r($getIdElem);
```

but I'm getting **Date:** with ID string while its having space before it. Output of printing an array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1
    [1] => 200
    [2] => OK
    [3] => ID=347
Date:
    [4] => Tue,
    [5] => 19
    [6] => Feb
    [7] => 2013
    [8] => 09:15:25
    [9] => GMT
Server:
    [10] => Apache/2.2.22
    [11] => (Ubuntu)
Content-length:
    [12] => 0
Vary:
    [13] => Accept-Encoding
Content-Type:
    [14] => text/plain;
    [15] => charset=ISO-8859-1


)
```

I don't understand why it doesn't include that space in explode function. Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: There is not a space but a newline in between.

Comment: What makes you think that all those HTTP headers are in a single line?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario as its having text/plain response from the server

Comment: @str Thanks I'm new bie to PHP so just need to ask that how can we exploade it with new line?

Comment: `explode("\n", $output)`

Comment: @str I've tried that but same output. I think silkfire has an idea to get rid from all the string functions. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex instead:

```
if (preg_match('# ID=(\d+) #', $response, $match)) { 
   $id = $match[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks silkfire, its much easier than running couple of string functions.

Answer (score 1):

It's a new line before Date, not a space. You'd be best trying a regex to extract the bits you want.